# DFS Traversal Iterative

Tags: graph, iteration, traversal, depth-first-search

I'm trying to understand the difference between DFS Recursive and DFS iterative. In this problem, the neighbors are iterated in alphabetical order.

Using DFS recursive, I get A, C, D, E, F. However, I do not understand the process of DFS iterative traversal. My professor says using a DFS iterative method, A E D C F should be obtained. Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Here is the image: [image]

Answer (score 0):

For a graph, there can be more then 1 way to traverse the node using DFS and starting from the same source. 
Take your graph represented as an adjancency list, for example. It can be:

```
B: A
A: C, D, E
C: D, E, F
F: D
```

or

```
B: A
A: E, D, C
C: F, D, E
F: D
```

Both are valid representations.
But if you implement it by choosing the tails in the order they appear in the list of neighbours, the first will lead to: A->C->D->E->F, while the second will lead A->E->D->C->F. Both are valid traversals.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of running time, both are about the same.

If anything, using an iterative DFS should be very marginally faster because the stack frame doesn't have to be returned whenever a recursive function returns.

To answer your question, your recursive DFS doesn't use a stack whereas your iterative one does. Thus, your recursive DFS will look at all of the neighbors, and execute DFS immediately if the neighbor is not found yet. That is why the order is A,C,D,..,etc. For your iterative DFS, it utilizes a stack, so the last stored node will be traversed first. Since we are going by alphabetical order, E would be stored last, so it will be traversed first from A. And then it would be D, C, and so on.